# Metasploit targets list import

Tags: metasploit

I would like to know if in metasploit for any given exploit its possible to use a target list instead of a single target and if possible how is that done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally, this worked for non-exploits using [RHOSTS](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/port-scanning/):

> Scanners and most other auxiliary modules use the ‘RHOSTS’ option
>   instead of ‘RHOST’. RHOSTS can take IP ranges
>   (192.168.1.20-192.168.1.30), CIDR ranges (192.168.1.0/24), multiple
>   ranges separated by commas (192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.3.0/24), and
>   line-separated host list files (file:/tmp/hostlist.txt).

[Recent work](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/9246) extended RHOSTS usage to include exploits, as well:

```
msf5 exploit(linux/ssh/symantec_smg_ssh) > set RHOSTS 172.16.185.218, 172.16.231.122
RHOSTS => 172.16.185.218, 172.16.231.122
msf5 exploit(linux/ssh/symantec_smg_ssh) > run
[*] Exploiting target 172.16.185.218

[*] 172.16.185.218:22 - Attempt to login...
[-] 172.16.185.218:22 SSH - Failed authentication
[*] Exploiting target 172.16.231.122
[*] 172.16.231.122:22 - Attempt to login...
[-] 172.16.231.122:22 SSH - Failed authentication
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
msf5 exploit(linux/ssh/symantec_smg_ssh)
```

This also works with files as described:

```
$ cat /tmp/hostlist.txt
172.16.185.218
172.16.231.122
$ fg
msfconsole

msf5 exploit(linux/ssh/symantec_smg_ssh) > set RHOSTS file:/tmp/hostlist.txt
RHOSTS => file:/tmp/hostlist.txt
msf5 exploit(linux/ssh/symantec_smg_ssh) > run
[*] Exploiting target 172.16.185.218

[*] 172.16.185.218:22 - Attempt to login...
[-] 172.16.185.218:22 SSH - Failed authentication
[*] Exploiting target 172.16.231.122
[*] 172.16.231.122:22 - Attempt to login...
[-] 172.16.231.122:22 SSH - Failed authentication
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
msf5 exploit(linux/ssh/symantec_smg_ssh)
```

Comment: Don't know why I get this error '> run
[-] Auxiliary failed: Msf::OptionValidateError One or more options failed to validate: RHOSTS.' using a file (one host per line)

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil   I have same problem, I checked my hosts file and I found still containing some DOMAIN (failed when my script resolve them to ip some of that domain) , it's all must be an IP address, so I just remove it and worked fine